# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, slideshow, runnable

I have made an android app,In that I am getting an arrayList of ImageUrls,I want to make an automated lsideShow in android by using this arrayLis,I have tried as below using thread but It gives me arrayIndexOPutOfBounds exception,It goes to second image abd then gives exception,Please help me to save me,My code is as below:

```
resultArray = new ArrayList<String>();
iv_paly.setOnClickListener(new OnCLickListener()){

@Override
OnClick(){
            imageLoader.displayImage(resultArray.get(1), proImage, options);
            proImage.postDelayed(swapImage, 3000);
}
MediaPlayer introSound, bellSound;
    Runnable swapImage = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i <= resultArray.size(); i++) {
                imageLoader.displayImage(resultArray.get(i), proImage, options);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= resultArray.size(); i++)` means that if size = 2 you try to use items 0, 1, 2 of the array. Too bad there are not 3 items but 2. Use < instead of <=

Comment: @StephaneM 
Thank you dear freiend..But can you tell me please how to make slide show this way,I am getting only two images then my slide show stops..:(..Hopw you will help me friend..Thank you.

Comment: Your question was solved, please accept the answer most appropriate by clicking the little checkmark next to it. If you have another problem, please ask a new question. Please refrain from asking people to write your app for you, instead show what you're trying and what exactly is going wrong, preferably also adding your error logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= resultArray.size(); i++) {
```

into:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.size(); i++) {
```

you can use `for(String s: resultArray){...}` as well, if you don't care about the index so much...

Comment: the answer gets downvoted, because...?

Answer (score 2):

remove "=",

```
for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.size(); i++) {
            imageLoader.displayImage(resultArray.get(i), proImage, options);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of arrays are zerobased in java you have to wrote `<resultArray.size();` and not `<=resultArray.size();`

```
for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.size(); i++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.size(); i++) {
    imageLoader.displayImage(resultArray.get(i), proImage, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexes of Array are zero based, so if your Array size is 10 it should count from [0] till [9]. You would never have a [10] element in that case. In your for loop, you iterate from [0] till [10], which results in a `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` error because you want the 11th element in your Array (and that does not exist).

So basically change

```
for (int i = 0; i <= resultArray.size(); i++) {
    imageLoader.displayImage(resultArray.get(i), proImage, options);
}
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.size(); i++) {
    imageLoader.displayImage(resultArray.get(i), proImage, options);
}
```